# Fragment Activity Handling

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, activitygroup

I am in the process of learning Android to port over an iOS app that I created.  I am having some trouble understanding how to have multiple active activities on screen at once whether it be through a ActivityGroup or FragmentActivity.  ActivityGroup is deprecated but almost seems like the best approach.

I could use some help in determining the correct (or best) approach before diving into further details.

Here is what I am trying to create:

The app should be broken into three visual sections:
1) Top 50dp for a dynamic banner that persists.
2) Main Content Area in the middle for a viewpager dashboard with icons that allows navigation to other activities and replaces itself.
3) Bottom 30 dp music player bar.

Essentially, I want the Ad bar and Player bar work independent of the main content area.  For example, when a button is pressed in the main content area, I would like the main content area to be replaced with a new activity such as a listview of tracks, a webview, a map view, etc.  The back button would return the main content area to the dashboard view pager.

There would also be cases where I would like to be able to hide the top and bottom bars to make the main content area full screen and also cases where I would like an activity presented full screen to replace all 3 visually (such as accessing a mail composer intent, contacts intent, etc.)

I've been able to put together a FragmentActivity that separates the app into a top fragment, middle viewpager controlled by the FragmentActivity, and bottom fragment but this seems like it wouldn't be the best approach as the fragments are not activities themselves and replacing the view pager with a new activity would require replacing the entire FragmentActivity itself.

To the point, what would be the best layout approach to implement this format (with 2.1+ support).

Thanks,
James

Added Current Code:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        android:name="com.dmi.AnywhereArtist.AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/ad_fragment" >
    </fragment>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:id="@+id/main_pager"
    android:layout_weight="100" 
    android:background= "#00aa00" />
    <fragment
        android:name="com.dmi.AnywhereArtist.PlayerFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/player_fragment" >
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Fragments.

An important thing to keep in mind is that Android only allows one Activity to run at a time, even if multiple activities are visible on screen.

Fragments work around this problem by allowing you to take modular application components and combine them, while still keeping everything inside of a single Activity.

What you're trying to do is exactly what Fragments were designed for.

(And to get 2.1+ support, use the Support Package: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html. Though, keep in mind that the Support Package doesn't support MapFragments.)

Answer (score 0):

> I am having some trouble understanding how to have multiple active activities on screen at once

That is because you should not do this. It was a bad approach from the beginning and is unnecessary now. Use fragments, please.

> I've been able to put together a FragmentActivity that separates the app into a top fragment, middle viewpager controlled by the FragmentActivity, and bottom fragment but this seems like it wouldn't be the best approach as the fragments are not activities themselves and replacing the view pager with a new activity would require replacing the entire FragmentActivity itself.

Your described approach seems fine. Use fragments in a `ViewPager` for your main area. Use the Android Support package to get fragment support going back to Android 1.6.

Comment: Ok.  I guess where my biggest confusion is lies is how you can treat fragments as there own independent classes with life cycles like an activity.  For instance, if I use a ViewPager for my main area, how do I replace it with a totally different piece of content (i.e. a table) and keep the handling of that content separate from the main view pager dashboard.  I wouldn't want to the main content area to act like a view pager except when it is the dashboard.

Comment: @JamesR.Cahall: "I wouldn't want to the main content area to act like a view pager except when it is the dashboard" -- um, well, you can't have it both ways. You can't say that the user can leave the dashboard via a swipe but cannot return via a swipe and still use `ViewPager`. Dashboards and `ViewPager` make little sense in tandem, IMHO, but it's possible that you are using the terms in ways that differ from how Android developers use them. Regardless, you are welcome to have your main content area be a `FrameLayout` and use `FragmentTransactions` to switch out what fragment is shown there.

Comment: Ok.  So if my main area is a FrameLayout instead of a ViewPager, and I use FragmentTransactions, can I have a ViewPager inside a fragment? All of the examples I have seen have had ViewPager extending an Activity and created in onCreate() vs. the fragment format of onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) inflation

Comment: @JamesR.Cahall: "can I have a ViewPager inside a fragment?" -- sure. "All of the examples I have seen have had ViewPager extending an Activity" -- `ViewPager` never `extends Activity`.